# Onmousedown / OnmouseUp issue with website

Tags: javascript, php, html, getelementsbyclassname

I'm trying to make my arrows (image files) change color when clicked with this code:

```
<img id="imag" src="img/left.png" onmousedown="DownLeft()" onmouseup="UpLeft()">

<img id="img" src="img/right.png" onmousedown="mouseDown()" onmouseup="mouseUp()">

    <script> 
function mouseDown() {
    document.getElementById("img").src="img/right-hover.png"; 
}

    function mouseUp() {
    document.getElementById("img").src="img/right.png"; }

    function DownLeft() {
    document.getElementById("imag").src="img/left-hover.png";}

    function UpLeft() {
    document.getElementById("imag").src="img/left.png";} </script>
```

The idea is when the one of the images is clicked they will turn blue as long as they are clicked but the code does just work for the right.png image and I have tried so many things to make it for both but with no luck! Am I overseeing something? I will very much appreciate some answers or help.

Comment: make sure you have named the file correctly, because its look alright from here.

Answer (score 0):

If the image is clicked, the page change or the page refresh so you must use php to know if the link was cliked or not and change the image.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the error was, but when I tried again with the same code as above a couple minutes after posting the question here it just worked! So no problem anymore